# JS: Flatten array of array while mapping through it?

Tags: javascript

If I want the colors of the following data, I know I can do :
`let colors = foo.foo.data.map(x => x.colors)` which will give me an array of arrays:

`[['yellow', 'green'],['grey','pink'],['white', 'willow']]

Is there a way to flatten that while mapping through it rather than doing a separate iteration to flatten after it's mapped ?

```
let foo = { foo: {
    data: [
        {
           name: "asdd",
           age: 55, 
           colors: ["red", "black"]
        },
        {
           name: "Richard",
           age: 12, 
           colors: ["yellow", "green"]
        },  
        {
           name: "Marcus",
           age: 99, 
           colors: ["grey", "pink"]
        },
        {
           name: "Ian",
           age: 24, 
           colors: ["white", "willow"]
        }, 
    ]
}}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: never knew flatMap existed, thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to flatten that while mapping through it rather than
> doing a separate iteration to flatten after it's mapped ?

Yes, you can use [.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which will flatten the returned results into one outer resulting array like so:

```js
let foo = { foo: { data: [{ name: "asdd", age: 55, colors: ["red", "black"] }, { name: "Richard", age: 12, colors: ["yellow", "green"] }, { name: "Marcus", age: 99, colors: ["grey", "pink"] }, { name: "Ian", age: 24, colors: ["white", "willow"] }, ] } };
let colors = foo.foo.data.flatMap(x => x.colors);
console.log(colors);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap`. It will create a flat array with the elements.

```
foo.foo.data.flatMap(x => x.colors)
```

```js
let foo = { foo: { data: [{ name: "asdd", age: 55, colors: ["red", "black"] }, { name: "Richard", age: 12, colors: ["yellow", "green"] }, { name: "Marcus", age: 99, colors: ["grey", "pink"] }, { name: "Ian", age: 24, colors: ["white", "willow"] }, ] } }
let colors = foo.foo.data.flatMap(x => x.colors)
console.log(colors)

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Or you can use `reduce` and `concat` too.

```
foo.foo.data.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x.colors), []);
```

```js
let foo = { foo: { data: [{ name: "asdd", age: 55, colors: ["red", "black"] }, { name: "Richard", age: 12, colors: ["yellow", "green"] }, { name: "Marcus", age: 99, colors: ["grey", "pink"] }, { name: "Ian", age: 24, colors: ["white", "willow"] }, ] } }

let colors = foo.foo.data.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x.colors), []);
console.log(colors)
```

But this is inefficient and should be avoided for large arrays.

Refer [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 0):

You can flat with reduce method, try this:

```js
let foo = { foo: {
    data: [
        {
           name: "asdd",
           age: 55, 
           colors: ["red", "black"]
        },
        {
           name: "Richard",
           age: 12, 
           colors: ["yellow", "green"]
        },  
        {
           name: "Marcus",
           age: 99, 
           colors: ["grey", "pink"]
        },
        {
           name: "Ian",
           age: 24, 
           colors: ["white", "willow"]
        }, 
    ]
}};


let colors = foo.foo.data.map(x => x.colors).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);

console.log(colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as concise as `flatMap()` but this also works:

```
let colors = [];
foo.foo.data.forEach(elmt => colors = colors.concat(elmt.colors));
console.log(colors); // Array(8) [ "red", "black", "yellow", "green", "grey", "pink", "white", "willow" ]
```